# How to rearrange my data frame per year, with conditions and a calculation at the same time in R?

Tags: r

So I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame (ID  = c("A1","A1","A1","A2","A2","A3","A3","A3","A3","A4","A4","A4","A4"),
                  status = c(1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1),
                  value = c( 10,12,0,40,42,30,31,34,0,32,34,36,37),
                  year = c(2000,2005,2010,2005,2010,2000,2005,2010,2015,2000,2005,2010,2015
                  ))
```

I want to transform this `df` to keep only rows for values that appear 3 or more times in the `ID` column. I want to arrange it in a way to have per row values that reappear in 3 different years, with the `status` in each year and the differences between the `value` in second and first, and third and second year. The final `df` should look like this:

```
df <- data.frame (ID  = c("A1","A3","A3","A4","A4"),
                  Year1= c(2000,200,2005,2000,2005),
                  Year2 = c(2005,2005,2010,2005,2010),
                  Year3 = c(2010,2010,2015,2010,2015),
                  Value1 = c(10,30,31,32,34),
                  Value2 = c(12,31,34,34,36),
                  Value3 = c(0,34,0,36,37),
                  DiffValue1 = c(2,1,3,2,2),
                  DiffValue2 = c(0,3,0,2,1),
                  Status1 = c(1,1,1,1,1),
                  Status2 = c(1,1,1,1,1),
                  Status3 = c( 0,1,0,1,1)
)
```

I know I could start doing this step by step, first subsetting the data to keep only `ID`s that repeat 3 or more times, then rearrange rows to columns and calculating the differences in values, but is there a way to combine all of this into one snippet of code?

Comment: `A1` has a diff of `-12` from the second to third year, why is it `0` in your second `df`?

Comment: I know, I wanted it to be like that, the actual difference is -12, but if it is 0 in the second year  I want the ```DiffValue``` to be 0 as well

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
library(dplyr)
    
df %>%
   relocate(year, value, status, .after = ID) %>%
   group_by(ID) %>%
   filter(n() > 2) %>%
   mutate(diff = c(0, diff(value)) * status) %>%
   reframe(across(everything(), ~ data.frame(embed(rev(.x), 3), check.names = FALSE), .unpack = TRUE)) %>%
   arrange(ID, year_1) %>%
   select(-diff_1, diff_1 = diff_2, diff_2 = diff_3) %>%
   relocate(starts_with("status"), .after = last_col())

# A tibble: 5 × 12
  ID    year_1 year_2 year_3 value_1 value_2 value_3 diff_1 diff_2 status_1 status_2 status_3
  <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1 A1      2000   2005   2010      10      12       0      2      0        1        1        0
2 A3      2000   2005   2010      30      31      34      1      3        1        1        1
3 A3      2005   2010   2015      31      34       0      3      0        1        1        0
4 A4      2000   2005   2010      32      34      36      2      2        1        1        1
5 A4      2005   2010   2015      34      36      37      2      1        1        1        1
```

Comment: Hey, sorry for late reply! This works in this example, but my real datasets has the years all mixed up, they are not in ascending order. Because of that when I transform it, year1, year2 and year3 are not in ascending order but in the order how they show up in the data. Is there a way to add that year1 should be minimum year for that specific ID, and year3 the maximum?